# Filtro regresivo de raster

Tags: r

Tengo una serie de imágenes raster con pixeles fallidos y quiero reemplazar estos mediante un filtro temporal regresivo en donde el dia actual tome el valor del dia anterior, es decir, la imagen i-3 incorpore el procesado de i-2, i-2 la de i-1 y asi hasta i-n. Mi procesamiento es un subset en donde si el dia actual tiene valor 1 y el anterior 3 tome el valor de 3. Lo que no puedo hacer es que se el procesamiento se lleve a cabo de i a i-n.

```
#Filtro temporal
library(raster)
library(MODIS)
library(rgdal)
setwd("D:/Estacional")
mypath9<-"D:/SNOWL"
myras9<-list.files(path=mypath9,pattern = glob2rx("*.tif$"), 
                    full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
name9<-substr(myras9,16,28)

for (i in 363:93){
r<-raster(myras9[i])
r1<-raster(myras9[i-1])
r[(r1==3) & (r==1)]<-3  
writeRaster(r,paste0("MOYDTF2",name9[i], sep=""),datatype='INT1U',format="GTiff",overwrite=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y veas [ask] y para las preguntas trata de cumplir con un [mcve]. Algo más de detalle ayudará a poder responder tu pregunta, por ejemplo que es lo que buscas lograr, que entiendes por un filtro regresivo, que librerías son las que estas usando, etc. Saludos.

Comment: Apoyo lo dicho por Patricio, ¿cuál es el resultado que esperas al procesar los raster? Al parecer estás intentando utilizar categorías de un raster previo para reasignar nuevos valores al raster `i` ¿no?

Comment: @aldo_tapia así es, ahora edite la pregunta para esclarecer mejor que quiero hacer. Saludos

Comment: tmsppc, si la respuesta de Aldo te ha servido sería bueno para él y para otros usuarios que la marques como aceptada. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesante pregunta, especialmente si estás trabajando con un producto diario dentro de la serie de MODIS. Simplemente debes realizar una prueba lógica en el raster objetivo y ocupar la misma prueba lógica para obtener los valores del día anterior.

El ejemplo no ocupa un código parecido al tuyo, lo cree para que fuese reproducible, pero en rigor es exactamente igual, sólo que `r` será el apilado de los rasters que tienes, aunque el principio también funciona entre diferentes objetos.

Creamos un raster de prueba:

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis) # sólo para generar los levelplot() en este caso

r <- raster(nrows=10,ncol=10)

set.seed(1)
```

Asignamos valor por pixel y a su vez creamos algunos pixeles `NA` para reproducir el problema:

```
rList <- list()

teselasVacias <- sample(1:100,40,replace=F)

for(i in 1:4){
  rList[[i]] <- setValues(r,sample((0:99)+(i*200), 100, replace=F))
  rList[[i]][teselasVacias[(1:10)+((i-1)*10)]] <- NA
}

r <- stack(rList)

levelplot(r)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se utiliza la prueba lógica para determinar qué valor es `NA` en el raster que deseas rellenar con valores, misma prueba se usa para el raster origen de los pixeles de donde obtendrás el valor (en este caso, al ser un apilado se ocupa el índice anterior `i-1`:

```
for(i in 2:4){
  r[[i]][is.na(r[[i]])] <- r[[i-1]][is.na(r[[i]])]
}

levelplot(r)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el resultado se aprecia que el los valores fueron reemplazados con los pixeles del raster de índice anterior.

Comment: Gracias, tu respuesta me es muy util. Sin embargo me da el siguiente error: r <- stack(myras5[1:5])
r[[5]][(r==1)[[5]]] <- r[[5-1]][(r==3)[[5]]] ng message:
In .replace(x, i, value = value, recycle = 1) :
  número de items para para sustituir no es un múltiplo de la longitud del reemplazo
>

Comment: Es porque estás usando dos pruebas lógicas diferentes. `r==1` y `r==3` no necesariamente tendrán la misma longitud